# Permission denied when attempting to edit docker container files

Tags: docker, docker-compose, permission-denied, adminer

I'm working on a Dockerized project which has an Adminer container. I need to increase the value of *post_max_size* found in */usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/0-upload_large_dumps.ini*.

My problem is any attempt to edit the file results in **permission denied** responses. Usually, this would be a prolem resolved by using sudo but I also get permission denied from that as well.

The following is the output of the directory I'm trying to edit showing the target file is owned by root:

```
/var/www/html $ cd /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d $ ls -l
total 24
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           113 Nov 18 22:10 0-upload_large_dumps.ini
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            23 Nov 18 22:11 docker-php-ext-pdo_dblib.ini
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            23 Nov 18 22:10 docker-php-ext-pdo_mysql.ini
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            22 Nov 18 22:11 docker-php-ext-pdo_odbc.ini
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            23 Nov 18 22:11 docker-php-ext-pdo_pgsql.ini
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            17 Nov 18 17:03 docker-php-ext-sodium.ini
```

And the adminer section of docker-compose is as follows:

```
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    labels:
      - traefik.port=8080
      - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:adminer
```

How can I edit docker-compose so I have permissions to update the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing to change in your `docker-compose.yaml`.
If you want to change it, you can just `exec` in the container as the root user.

So I suppose that, right now, you are doing

```sh
docker compose exec adminer ash
```

And then, you are trying to edit those file.

What you can do, instead, is:

```sh
docker compose exec --user root adminer ash
```

So you will be able to adapt those files owned by root.

---

This said, mind that the philosophy of Docker is that a container should be short lived, so you would be better having your own *Dockerfile* to edit that configuration file for good. Another way to do it would be to mount a file over the existing one to change the configurations.

Example of adaptation in a *Dockerfile*:

```sh
FROM adminer 

COPY ./0-upload_large_dumps.ini \
     /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/0-upload_large_dumps.ini
## ^-- copies a files from the folder where you build
## in order to override the existing configuration
```

Then in your `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
  adminer:
    build: .
    image: your-own-namespace/adminer
    restart: always
    labels:
      - traefik.port=8080
      - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:adminer
```

Example of mounting a file to override the configuration file:

```yaml
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    labels:
      - traefik.port=8080
      - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:adminer
    volumes:
      - "./0-upload_large_dumps.ini:\
        /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/0-upload_large_dumps.ini"
## a local file `0-upload_large_dumps.ini` on your host
## will override the container ini file
```